# State of element before and after editing (using contentEditable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to capture how the elements within a div change after a user edits it (as the content is contentEditable), and so have a page like the following:

```js
before_html = $("#example_div").children();
$("#differences_button").on("click",function(){
  after_html = $("#example_div").children();
  console.dir(before_html[0].innerText);
  console.dir(after_html[0].innerText);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example_div" contentEditable><span id='example_span'>How it starts</span></div>
<button type="button" id="differences_button">Show differences</button>
```

However, as the console.dirs show, the "before_html" doesn't store the original structure of the element, but will show you the latest structure of it when running it again.

Is there a way to store the structure before the sort of changes shown in this example?

I've tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(before_html)) to store something that won't update, which often works when trying to store a javascript variable you don't want later update, but this fails to store the content when applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing `before_html[0].innerText` and `after_html[0].innerText` after the click. So both of them are evaluated after all changes are made.

Instead, you can save `before_html` (prior to attaching the event handler), and have it contain the innerHtml or innerText, and then compare with the new value during the click handler.

```js
before_text = $("#example_div").text();
$("#differences_button").on("click",function(){
  after_text = $("#example_div").text();
  console.dir(before_text);
  console.dir(after_text);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example_div" contentEditable><span id='example_span'>How it starts</span></div>
<button type="button" id="differences_button">Show differences</button>
```

---

<sub>Note that I have changed the variable name from `before_html` to `before_text` as it doesn't contain HTML. You can have it contain HTML by calling `before_text = $("#example_div").html();` if you prefer that.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I could store more than just the text though (even though in my example the text is what I access). Is there a way to do this without having to individually store each aspect you want later?

Comment: @itHaffens Yeah I was wondering about the same thing as I read the question. But I am not sure if the standard allows for that. I will have to check. A decent workaround would be something like listening to a focus or a click event on the content editable, and then blur event to get a list of changes.